# sql query to get drop off points of a user

Tags: mysql

I have a table provided on the pic below.
The order of the index is the steps of the messages, it tells me where the user ended to chat with the bot.

So, now I am trying to get all the last step of the order_index with it's message.

e.g (4, thanks for the info), (4 thanks for the info), (2, what is your phone number), (2, what is your phone number)

I only want to get where the bot message is true, if maybe the user ended on 3 and the message is my phone number is `0123456789`, I would like to go one step back to get the bot message.

[image]

Comment: Is there any column which is unique to a set of messages, like a common id for message (0,1,2,3)?

Comment: first you need a way to associate all the messages in a single chat. Right now there's no way to know that definitively. You need another field, as Sandesh mentioned, to identify a specific conversation and associate messages with it.

Comment: @ Sandesh Gupta yes i do have a message id to identify every message

Comment: Where is that identity column? @SindisoDube

Answer (score 0):

If you have `message_id` as unique identifier, then you can group records using `group by`

```
WITH ABC AS (SELECT MAX(order_index) AS order_index,message_id FROM MESSAGES GROUP BY message_id)
SELECT MESSAGE FROM MESSAGES 
INNER JOIN 
ABC 
ON ABC.message_id = MESSAGES.message_id 
   AND ABC.order_index= MESSAGES.order_index;
```